# Is it possible to dim the light of iPhone's camera flash light programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4

Is it possible to dim the light of iPhone's camera flash light programmatically?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS5 will help you with this. It is still under NDA. I suggest you look in the beta documentation for AVCaptureDevice or ask on the Apple developer forum.

It is not possible in iOS4.3.

When the NDA is lifted I will edit this response to give the documentation link.

EDIT

Sorry, it looks like Apple removed the ability to change the torch level in the public release of iOS5. The [`torchLevel`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009520-CH1-SW90) property of `AVCaptureDevice` is now read-only.

Comment: Do you have the iOS 5 documentation link?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009520-CH1-SW90

Comment: As of iOS 6.0, there is a new call, `setTorchModeOnWithLevel`, which allows you to set the torch level.


    `- (BOOL)setTorchModeOnWithLevel:(float)torchLevel error:(NSError **)outError`

Answer (score 3):

As of iOS 6.0, there is a new call, `setTorchModeOnWithLevel`, which allows you to set the torch level.

```
- (BOOL)setTorchModeOnWithLevel:(float)torchLevel error:(NSError **)outError
```

Comment: which. inconveniently. is broken on 8.1.1 I've filed bug 19083935 with apple

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work i think:

```
AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
if ([device hasTorch]) {
  [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
  [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOff];
  [device unlockForConfiguration];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I am not wrong, this will only set the torch ON and OFF...right? Is there a way to change light intensity of the torch? Please let me know.

Comment: Don't think so, only ON, OFF and AUTO. Can't find anything about settings it gradually in the documentation. http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that still they have these controls in Public APIs for the developers to change it.

I think we can turn it on or off as it is many torch applications but I don't think we can decrease the intensity(i.e. dim the flash light) .

There are signs that this may get into public API onc iOS5 is launched but for now, it is not possible.

Also using iOS5 beta for development would not help as some of the features in iOS5 are still errorneous and are yet to be solved.

Hopefully it will get resolved in the final release.

Hope this helps you. :)